# An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update"

Tags: android, eclipse

My Android project was working fine initially. After updating SDK to version 22.0.4, getting 'An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update".' on starting eclipse. Error: Unbound classpath variable error. I tried to restart eclipse, its giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path remove the unwanted files in the order& export tab and check the Android Dependicies, Android Private Libraries in the same tab.

Answer (score 1):

Check `Window > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables` for any anomalies. Better yet, if you are notified which variable is unbound then look for that variable in this list.